# Getting CloudTrail Logs into Logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to get logs from ClouldTrail into ElasticSearch so that we can see what is going on in our AWS account better.

I have set up both Logstash and ElasticSearch on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04), and can push text from `stdin` to ElasticSearch. However when I try to use the S3 input nothing is added to ElasticSearch.

Here is the conf file Im using, I have removed my amazon keys

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => 'ko-cloudtrail-log-bucket'
    secret_access_key => ''
    access_key_id => ''
    delete => false
    interval => '60'
    region => 'eu-west-1'
    type => 'CloudTrail'
    codec => cloudtrail {}
    }
}

output {
    stdout {}
    elasticsearch {
            host => '127.0.0.1'
     }
}
```

I have install the [logstash-codec-cloudtrail](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-codec-cloudtrail/versions/0.1.4) codec but the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-codec-cloudtrail/0.1.4#Documentation) is pretty sparse.

I get no errors in my terminal even when running Logstash with -v and nothing is printed to `stdout`. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

Here's my cloudtrail input. It works great with one minor issue- it duplicates records. As the `prefix` indicates, I put the cloudtrail logs at s3://bucketname/cloudtrail, not the root.

**The mutations are optional**. The eventSource mutation is to make the logs a little more readable, and the ruby ingest_time gives me a date the record showed up in ELK- otherwise, it only has the time of the event. Finally, I drop a very common record that just adds noise to my system.

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "bucketname"
    delete => false
    interval => 60 # seconds
    prefix => "cloudtrail/"
    type => "cloudtrail"
    codec => "cloudtrail"
    credentials => "/etc/logstash/s3_credentials.ini"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash_cloudtrail/sincedb"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "cloudtrail" {
    mutate {
      gsub => [ "eventSource", "\.amazonaws\.com$", "" ]
      add_field => {
        "document_id" => "%{eventID}"
      }
    }
    if ! [ingest_time] {
      ruby {
        code => "event['ingest_time'] = Time.now.utc.strftime '%FT%TZ'"
      }
    }


    if [eventSource] == "elasticloadbalancing" and [eventName] == "describeInstanceHealth" and [userIdentity.userName] == "secret_username" {
      drop {}
    }
  }
}
```

The credentials.ini format is explained on the [s3 input page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/s3); it's just this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work for me either. What version of logstash are you using as I am using 1.4.2