# Unable to read .gz files in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am trying to read .gz files in logstash input plugin but I can't read gunzip files in logstash. When I try to read those log files it throws error message like this,

> A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin. Plugin:
>   ["/test.txt"],
>   start_position=>"beginning", sincedb_path=>"/dev/null",
>   codec=>"UTF-8">,
>   stat_interval=>1, discover_interval=>15, sincedb_write_interval=>15,
>   delimiter=>"\n">
>
> Error: Object:
>   sample.gz is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to
>   "read". {:level=>:error}

LogStash.conf file:

```
file {
   path => "/test.txt" (this file contains list of gunzip files)
   start_position => "beginning"
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"``
   codec => "gzip_lines"
}
```

and also tried path => `"/logfile.gz"` directly but both are not working it throws same error message.
How to solve this problem, please share your solutions. I refered all the similar questions but none of the solutions solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logstash cloudfront codec plugin: Error: Object: #Version: 1.0 is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to "read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840020/logstash-cloudfront-codec-plugin-error-object-version-1-0-is-not-a-legal-ar)

Comment: I have to read .gz files but in this post "logstash cloudfront codec plugin: Error: Object: #Version: 1.0 is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to "read" here you are reading normal log files right? then how it resolves my error?

Answer (score 0):

Path should be an array of string representing path values not a string.

change your file input to below

```
file {
   path => ["test.gz",test_*.gz] #you can specify all those paths comma separated with wildcard also
   start_position => "beginning"
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"``
   codec => "gzip_lines"
}
```